# How to zoom area

Tags: mesh

With the reference of coreldraw software if we want to zoom particular area we just click on the magnify icon and drag and select the area. And it zoom the particular area.

[image]

Is there any way or hot key to zoom to a particular not with the mouse wheel scrolling many times adjusting or just clicking the dot (.) key. Some what similar to above example like coreldraw software. So that i can focus on that area.

Comment: Shift+B to "zoom border" is nearly what you describe here (you find it in the view menu of the 3D view)

Comment: @lemon yes thats perfect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender has several ways to zoom in the scene.

The one asked here is named "zoom border" and can be found with its shorcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> in the "view" menu of the 3D View.

[image]

The behavior is adaptive to the view mode (perspective like above or ortho, like below).

[image]

I think zooming using the mouse wheel or the <kbd>Num+</kbd> or <kbd>Num-</kbd> of the keypad is well known. But there is two other options which are a bit more hidden.

The first one is "zoom to mouse position". It can be set via user preferences. With it the zoom focuses to the position of the mouse pointer.

Note that works in all views (in the image editor too, for instance) and the "zoom border" is only available in the 3D view (as far as I know).

[image]

The second is concerning people who has no mouse wheel or using a track pad (when "emulate 3 button mouse" option is set in the "input" tab of the user preferences).

With it checked, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and left click in the viewport and move the mouse up or down to zoom in or out.

Comment: Zoom To Border works in Node editor and UV editor as well via Shift+B but in the viewport it requires some finite depth, so no way to navigate with it in empty scene.